# ruby on rails - No route matches [POST] "/login/index"

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i am pretty new to rails, and i recently have a problem..
I made a login page which looks like that:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<div id="content">
    <form action="#" method="POST" id="login-form">
        <fieldset>
            <p>
                <label for="login-username">username</label>
                <input type="text" id="login-username" class="round full-width-input" autofocus />
            </p>
            <p>
                <label for="login-password">password</label>
                <input type="password" id="login-password" class="round full-width-input" />
            </p>
            <!--<a href="dashboard.html" class="button round blue image-right ic-right-arrow">LOG IN</a>
            <%= link_to "Add to your favorites list", '/login/index', { :class=>"button round blue image-right ic-right-arrow" }  %>-->
            <%= submit_tag "Login" %>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
</div> <!-- end content -->
```

And this view in under app/views/login/index.html.erb
the matching controller is under app/controllers/login_controller.erb, and looks like that:

```
class LoginController < ApplicationController
  def index
  end

  def login
  end

end
```

and my routing looks like that:

```
BonhamNew::Application.routes.draw do

  get "login/index"
  # The priority is based upon order of creation: first created -> highest priority.
  # See how all your routes lay out with "rake routes".

  # You can have the root of your site routed with "root"
  root 'login#index'
end
```

when i click on the sumbit, i get:
No route matches [POST] "/login/index"

I know its pretty basic, but maybe some1 can give me a hand here ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create an additional route `post "login/index"`

Comment: Hi, it seems to work, but now when i click of the button, i get: ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken in LoginController#index                        What can cause that issue ?

Comment: @gal, that is to do with you not using the `form_tag` helper, see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You should add the route to your `routes.rb` file as `post 'login/index'` in addition to the get route. This will make sure the form doesn't cause an error, but keeps the behaviour as is, with the form sending the request to `login#index` not `login#login`.

Also, instead of explicitly using HTML form tags, use the [`form_tag`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-form_tag) helper. It is better practise in rails, and allows you to use HTTP methods that your browser might not support, like PUT and DELETE. It also adds fields that Rails needs to make sure your form is not being sent via a cross site request. (The authenticity token)

Also note the `text_field_tag`, `label_tag` and `password_field_tag` helpers on the same page as the `form_tag` above. You should get into the habit of using these in preference to raw HTML.

Comment: You should correct `post login/index` to `post 'login/index'`

Answer (score 0):

Read up on [resourceful routing in Rails](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resource-routing-the-rails-default). The examples there only use ActiveRecord models for resources, but you could also make one without an ActiveRecord model.

Login could be considered as a resource, where creating a login would not create a database record, but instead log the user into the application.

In your routes.rb define a resource as follows:

```
BonhamNew::Application.routes.draw do
  resource :login, only: [:show, :create]
end
```

This would make your controller as follows:

```
class LoginsController
  def show
    # Renders a page with the login form
  end

  def create
    # Logs the user in, your old login action
  end
end
```

Notice how the name of the controller by default is the plural form, `LoginsController`. If you want the singular name, just specify the controller to use for your resource as follows:

```
resource :login, controller: 'login', only: [:show, :create]
```

Then your controller looks like this:

```
class LoginController
  # actions
end
```